# Differential Equation has a unique solution periodic

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

Let $A(t)$ continuous and periodic of period $S$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $x' = Ax$ has $\varphi \equiv 0$ as the only periodic solution of period $S$. Show that there exists $\delta> 0$ such that for every continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \times E \longrightarrow E $, $S$ period of periodic with variable the first $|D_2f(t,x)|<\delta$ to all $(t,x)$ so $x' = A(t)x + f(t,x)$ has a unique periodic solution $\varphi_f$ of period $S$ also prove that if $f\rightarrow0$ uniformly then $\varphi \rightarrow 0$ uniformly.

Comment: Any thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need $f(t, 0) = 0$, all $t$?

Comment: Conclude that for every continuous function $b$ $S$ period, there is a unique solution $varphi_b $S$, of $x'= A(t)x + f(t,b(t))$. Show that the application $b \rightarrow \varphi_b$ it is a contraction if $\delta$ is small

Comment: We do not have this hypothesis.

Comment: OK.  Also, there is a $LaTex$ error in your comment.  Cheers.

Comment: sorry I could not fix